# KG on AdS space-time

Tags: ads-cft, klein-gordon-equation, anti-de-sitter-spacetime

In his [TASI notes](https://arxiv.org/abs/1802.08267) Oliver DeWolfe starts with the KG equation on the Poincaré patch metric
$$
ds^2=\frac{r^2}{L^2}(-dt^2+dx^2)+\frac{L^2}{r^2}dr^2.
$$
When we use the ansatz$$
\phi(r\rightarrow\infty,x,t)=\frac{\alpha(x,t)L^{2\Delta_-}}{r^{\Delta_-}}+\dots+\frac{\beta(x,t)L^{2\Delta_+}}{r^{\Delta_+}}+\dots
$$
on the KG equation
$$
\left(-\frac{1}{\sqrt{-g}}\partial_\mu\sqrt{-g}g^{\mu\nu}\partial_\nu+m^2\right)\phi=0
$$
we end up with an equation which is an ODE in r since the $\partial_t^2$,$\partial_x^2$ terms have a factor ${1}/{r^2}$ which we can ignore.

The equation I end up with is
$$
-\frac{3r}{L^2}\partial_r\phi-\frac{r^2}{L^2}\partial_r^2\phi+m^2\phi=0.
$$

When I substitute the ansatz I don't confirm that the equation is satisfied since I have a lot of terms with different powers of $r$. How can I show that this is indeed satisfied?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve equations of the form
$$
ar^2 \partial^2_{r}\phi + b r \partial_r\phi  +c \phi=0
$$ 
with constants $a$, $b$, $c$ 
(which is what you have)
one sets 
$$
\phi(r) =r^\lambda
$$
so the equation becomes 
$$
(a\lambda(\lambda-1) +b\lambda +c)r^\lambda=0.
$$
Thus one solves the quadradic equation 
$$
a\lambda(\lambda-1) +b\lambda +c=0
$$ to get the two values of $\lambda$.

Comment: I am only interested in the ansatz given. I understand that you can solve the equation as any ode but I am trying to understand why we use this ansatz.

Comment: The ansatz given is identical to mine! The $\Delta_{\pm}$ in the ansatz  are just my $-\lambda$.I don't see what your problem is.  When one includes the $1/r^2$ terms it is more complicated, but it's still the usual Frobenius indicial equation at a regular singular point.